# Radio Streaming ¿Por qué se detiene?

Tags: android, stream, radio

La radio de mi app se detiene exactamente cada 7 minutos, ya intenté solucionarlo con las configuraciones de los teléfonos; sin embargo, no he tenido éxito.

¿Alguien puede decirme si es problema en el código?

Aquí les dejo el código con el que estoy trabajando.

```
package com.devit.priscillacc.radiomiel;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button programas_btn;
private Button btn;
private boolean playPause;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private boolean initialStage = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    programas_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.programas);
    programas_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            btn.setText("Play");
            playPause=false;
            Intent programas = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mujeres.class );
            startActivity(programas);
        }
    });

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audioStreamBtn);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!playPause) {
                btn.setText("Pause");

                if (initialStage) {
                    new Player().execute("http://192.99.44.11:9921");
                } else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                playPause = true;

            } else {
                btn.setText("Play");

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }

                playPause = false;
            }
        }
    });
}


class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Boolean prepared = false;

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    initialStage = true;
                    playPause = false;
                    btn.setText("Play");
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
            prepared = false;
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
        initialStage = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Espera un momento estamos iniciando...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

}
```